# Commenting out a protocol in a property declaration in UIKit

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I was looking at the UIKit code for UIAlertView and came across this:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;
```

Why is the UIAlertViewDelegate part commented out. Why not just include it?

Comment: I am also curious and would like to know.